Data does not appear in the table after the select button is clicked in a Java Swing application
I have written code to handle the "Select" button action (btnSelectActionPerformed()), where I try to take data from the selected row in one of the three tables and insert it into the other table using the loadData() method. However, after the "Select" button is pressed, the data does not appear in the destination table. Here is the code snippet I used:
private void btnPilihActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    String id, nama, harga;
    int tabelDipilih = -1; // -1 menandakan tidak ada pemilihan

    int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    int f = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
    int g = jTable3.getSelectedRow();

    if (i >= 0) {
        tabelDipilih = 1; // Dipilih dari jTable1
    } else if (f >= 0) {
        tabelDipilih = 2; // Dipilih dari jTable2
    } else if (g >= 0){
      tabelDipilih = 3; // Dipilih dari jTable3
    }

    try {
        switch (tabelDipilih) { //untuk tentukan tabel berdasarkan pilihan
            case 1: // Dipilih dari jTable1
                id = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                nama = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                harga = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
                loadData();
                break;
            case 2: // Dipilih dari jTable2
                id = jTable2.getValueAt(f, 0).toString();
                nama = jTable2.getValueAt(f, 1).toString();
                harga = jTable2.getValueAt(f, 4).toString();
                loadData();
                break;
            case 3: // Dipilih dari jTable3
                id = jTable3.getValueAt(g, 0).toString();
                nama = jTable3.getValueAt(g, 1).toString();
                harga = jTable3.getValueAt(g, 4).toString();
                loadData();
                break;
            default:
                // Tangani pemilihan tidak valid (misalnya, tampilkan pesan kesalahan)
    }
    } catch (Exception e)  {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal mengambil data menu. Silahkan coba lagi.");
        return;
    }                                        
    dispose ();
    }

After the pilih button is clicked, the data is entered into the table

Ensure that the variables id, nama, and harga are accessible inside the loadData() method. You can do this by either making them class-level variables or by modifying the loadData() method to accept parameters. loadData(id, nama, harga); And ensure you're properly handling the data in loadData(...)

So you have two buttons but show only one action listener - the problematic one or the working one? However, after the "Select" button is pressed, the data does not appear in the destination table. [...] After the pilih button is clicked, the data is entered into the table
